# Can a command in a shell pipeline determine the tty characteristics of its context?

Tags: shell, shell-script, pipe, io-redirection, stty

I have a bash script that columnizes a list of items. By default it will guess at the number of columns to output, based on the terminal width as reported by `stty size`. But when the script is in a pipeline, `stty` reports "Inappropriate ioctl for device".

What I want is to allow my script, when being executed as a command in the middle of a pipeline, to discover whether the pipeline it's part of is ultimately outputting to a tty - and if so, be able to stty its characteristics.

SOLUTION: As pointed out below, `stty -F /dev/tty` seems to work anywhere in a pipeline.

Comment: `tty` or `tty -s`  will tell you if you are connected to a tty, wheter explicitly (tty) or by return code (tty -s). I suspect that in middle of `  foo | myshell | bar `  that might not work, but you cna give a try.

Comment: maybe your script is not run in a pipeline ... so this question lacks context

Comment: Your term "tty context" is misleading. Even in the case of pipelines (as Stephen showed in his answer) your processes are attached to a tty (if not detached from the terminal). From any of the processes you can (for example) still output to `/dev/tty`. I suggest to rephrase your question in that respect.

Comment: RashaMatt, I had been objecting against your term "tty context". But you changed it meanwhile. Fine. WRT your comment; I don't understand what you mean by 'its "width"'.

Comment: @Janis, console width, as returned by `stty size`. Console width is required in order to intelligently guess at how to columnize output, e.g. as is done by `ls`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try things out with a script such as

```
#!/bin/sh

for fd in 0 1 2; do
    if [ -t $fd ]; then echo $fd is a TTY; fi
done
```

Running this I see that:

- if the script is run on its own, all three FDs are TTYs
- if the script is run at the start of a pipeline, `stdin` and `stderr` are TTYs
- if the script is run in the middle of a pipeline, `stderr` is a TTY
- if the script is run at the end of a pipeline, `stdout` and `stderr` are TTYs

That all seems logical. Obviously if the pipeline redirects `stderr` as well the behaviour will be different.

To answer your question in full, I don't think it's possible to determine the terminal characteristics in all cases, but if you can find a FD (examine all the entries in `/dev/fd`) that's a TTY, you can run `stty` on that... But it isn't possible from the middle of a pipeline to determine where the end of the pipeline is going.

As mentioned by [Janis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102438/janis), if you want to find out information about the controlling terminal, regardless of the pipeline, you can use `/dev/tty`, *e.g.* with `stty -F /dev/tty`; but that will fail if the script is run without a controlling terminal, *e.g.* from a `cron` job.

Comment: Thanks - this is a solution when the script is either the first (stdin works) or the last (stdout works) command in the pipeline. But when the script is nether first nor last, stty fails for file handles 0-2.

Comment: OK, it looks like `stty -F /dev/tty` succeeds at any point in the pipeline. Thanks!

Comment: That only works if there is a controlling TTY; so for example if your script is ever run in a cronjob it will fail.